# How to get modified time and size of any file using PHP?

Tags: php

How to get modified time and size of any file using PHP?

Comment: No Man Some Times Einstein forgets, that what is Energy :) just like that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From php.net
http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.stat.php

stat

(PHP 4, PHP 5)

stat — Gives information about a file

Answer (score 9):

[SplFileInfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php) provides a high level API to the file system:

```
$file = new SplFileInfo('path/to/file');
echo $file->getMTime();
echo $file->getSize();
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use this

```
echo date("m/d/Y",filemtime("latestime.php"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filemtime` and `filesize` functions for that.

**[More info here](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6032755.html)**